# Limiting posts in Ruby on Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a sidebar for a news application. In the application, I organize the `post` type by `rating`. Posts that have the rating `"sports"` should show up in my sidebar. But there are 6 posts with a ranking of `"sports"` at any given time.

I want ONE post tagged the ranking `"sports"` to show up in my sidebar. That post can not have the same `title` as the current `@post` for the show page. I tried this, and it isn't working.

I get

```
undefined method `limit' for #<Post:0x007f9b553ce1d0>
```

as an error when I try to open up the page locally. If I use `limit` on the out `@post` statement, `limit` works.

Can someone help?

```
 <div class="col-md-11 col-md-push-1 sidebar2">
        <div class="sidebar_head_container">
            <h4 class="sidebar_header text-center">Local News</h4>
        </div>
    <% @posts.each do |p| %>
            <% if p.ranking == "sports" %>
                <% if p.title != @post.title %>
                    <% p.limit(1) do |x| %>
                        <a href='/posts/<%= p.slug %>'>
                            <div class="photo_div">
                                <%= image_tag x.photo, class: "photo_small" %>
                                <h5 class="white_green"><%= x.title %></h5>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you update controller code here ???

Comment: (maybe) in your controller `@posts = Post.where(ranking: 'sports').where('title <> ?', @post.title).first`

Answer (score 0):

do want a random post or will the first one do.

you can do something like this.

`<% sidebar_post = @posts.select{ |p| p.ranking == "sports" && p.title != @post.title }.first %>`

and the just render that one.  The limit doesn't work since you are not dealing with an active record relation there, you are dealing with a post instance.

if you want a random element. just change `.first` to `.sample`

This also assumes that you are using @posts elsewhere in this controller/view.  If you are just using this to get the sidebar post, you can move it into the controller and do that request with sql/ar, which will likely be faster / more efficient.